# Can't use sub-query or variable in window frame

Tags: sql-server

Why can't I use a  sub-query, or variable in window frame statements like the code below:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION aaa (@i AS INT) 
    returns TABLE AS 
    RETURN 
    SELECT   sum(freight) OVER(partition BY custid ORDER BY orderdate rows 
    BETWEEN 1 following AND      @i following ) AS su,
             * 
    FROM     sales.orders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL here like below -. Dynamic SQL is not possible a function. Use a stored procedure and call that inside a function.

```
DECLARE @i AS INT
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT  * , sum(freight) OVER(partition BY custid ORDER BY orderdate rows 
        BETWEEN 1 following AND ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' following ) AS su                 
        FROM sales.orders'
EXEC ( @SQL )
```

If you can try to create the same with **hardcoded value**, you will able to create. See this **10 following** hardcoded value ..i am passsing.

```
CREATE FUNCTION aaa (@i AS INT) 
    returns TABLE AS 
    RETURN 
    SELECT   sum(freight) OVER(partition BY custid ORDER BY orderdate rows 
    BETWEEN 1 following AND  10 following ) AS su,             * 
    FROM     sales.orders
```

Comment: I appreciate you and its very helpful but I cant understand HARD CODED VALUE. Thank you

Comment: I mean you are not passing the value via a variable. Since we are passing value of i at run time that why it is not accepting. If we provide any hard code integer value like 10(in my example) it is working. I hope it help!